# Incluir retorno de um forEach dentro da url do background-image

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, node.js, express.js

Fala galera, estou precisando incluir o retorno de um forEach dentro da url de um background-image, por favor, podem me ajudar:

```
<!-- Slide 1 -->
<% DTSection0.forEach(function(row){ %>
       <div class="item" style="background-image: url(assets/img/site/slider/<%= row.imagem %>)"></div>
<% }); %>
```

Vejam ao colocar o <%= row.imagem %> dentro da url da erro e a imagem não carrega na página.

Estou usando Node.JS e minhas páginas são em .ejs.

[image: Print aqui]

Comment: Podes mostrar como está o HTML gerado pelo ejs?

Comment: Então, não está retornando nada... está vazio.

fiz um console.log e a consulta bem como o forEach está ok, o problema está nessa parte ai mesmo de incluir o <%= row.imagem %> dentro da  url

Comment: Mas aparece a `<div class="item"`?

Comment: tem razão Sergio, somente uma imagem deve estar item active, as demais tem que estar somente item, vou arrumar aqui e já posto a resposta, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

```
<!-- Slide 1 -->
<% DTSection0.forEach(function(row){ 
    if(row.active == 1){ %>
      <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(assets/img/site/slider/<%= row.imagem %>)"></div>
    <% } else{ %>
      <div class="item" style="background-image: url(assets/img/site/slider/<%= row.imagem %>)"></div>
    <% }; %>
<% }); %>
```

O problema estava na class="item active", somente 1 imagem tem que estar active, as demais deve estar somente class="item".